# How can I tell whether a jackfruit has yellow or orange flesh by looking at the exterior of the jackfruit (i.e., without opening it)?

Tags: fruit, jackfruit

I prefer jackfruit with orange flesh over jackfruit with yellow flesh. How can I tell whether a jackfruit has yellow or orange flesh by looking at the exterior of the jackfruit (i.e., without opening it)?

---

Jackfruit with orange flesh:

[image]

[image]

Jackfruit with yellow flesh:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Would this help? It is a bit hit and miss because you don't see the tree or possibly don't have access to the information on the cultivar like there is usually with apples (e.g. royal gala, jonagold, red delicious, etc.), but hey https://www.growables.org/information/TropicalFruit/jackfruitvarieties.htm

Comment: @JulianaKarasawaSouza thanks, very cool, you are welcome to convert your comment into an answer.

Comment: Wow I didn't realize they were actually different varieties entirely. I feel kind of silly thinking about it in retrospect, because I definitely prefer the orange ones too! You should definitely convert to an answer, @Juliana .

Comment: Posted! Added another guide that I stumbled upon that has more pictures of fruit, so it might be handier for when you're at the shop

Answer (score 3):

It will be a bit hit and miss because you don't have all the information required to know which variety it is - like the tree itself or even information from the shop the same way as you have with other plants (like apples, they're often labeled with the cultivar name e.g. royal gala, jonagold, red delicious, etc.)

You can check some cultivar guides, like this one, which is pretty comprehensive:
https://www.growables.org/information/TropicalFruit/jackfruitvarieties.htm

This one has more pictures of the fruits, which might help when looking at the shelves:
http://www.virtualherbarium.org/tropicalfruit/jackfruit-cultivars.html